# How to set montserrat and mathptmx as default sans serif and serif typefaces, respectively in the same document?

Tags: typefaces

I'd like to set the default serif fault as Times (using mathptmx) and the default sans serif font to Montserrat (using montserrat).

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,scale=0.85]{montserrat}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\noindent \itshape \rmfamily Terms + Conditions \normalfont % I want this text in Times italics

\noindent\Large {\bfseries{AN ALL CAPS TITLE} \normalsize\normalfont 

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove `defaultfam`, whose purpose is to set Montserrat as the default text font.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[light,scale=0.85]{montserrat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

This is in Times and \textit{this is Times italics}

\textsf{This is in Montserrat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it would be better to use NewTX rather than `mathptmx` which is an old kludge.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[light,scale=0.85]{montserrat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb} % not needed with NewTX
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

This is in Times and \textit{this is Times italics}

\textsf{This is in Montserrat}

\end{document}
```